# How filter array of objects based on objects exists in another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have

```
array1 = [{ name: sample1 }, { name: sample2 }, { name: sample3 }];
array2 = [{ name: sample1 }, { name: sample2 }];
```

I want to filter objects of `array1` which exists in `array2`.
So I need to have

```
[{ name: sample1 }, { name: sample2 }]
```

How can I get it in javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you please share your attempt to get the results you are after!

Comment: I thought I can do it by filter.
`const array = array1.filter(item => array2.includes(item)).`
But it didn't work

Comment: Does `array2` contain references of the same object that are in `array1` OR its different objects but with same structure?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee it has same objects

Comment: Is every object guaranteed to contain only one key called `name`? If not, do you care about the existence of other keys?

Comment: So should I check each key in filter too, you mean?

Comment: if you only have one key called `name` in both arrays. you could do something like this to get the results are you are after -> `const arrr = arr1.filter(item => arr2.some(o2 => item.name === o2.name));`

Comment: it is more than 20 key @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Please edit your question to includes all the information you have. So thats its clear for all of us. We should be not going back and forth to get basic info about the question. Add all the info before posting.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping sure, thanks for comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the intersection of two sets while recognizing equal set values/items not only by reference but by their equal structures and entries too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71015428/how-to-get-the-intersection-of-two-sets-while-recognizing-equal-set-values-items)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  .filter and .some function in JavaScript ,
Here is the example

```
const array1 = [{ name: "sample1" }, { name: "sample2" }, { 
name: "sample3" }];
 const array2 = [{ name: "sample1" }, { name: "sample2" }];
let Result = array1.filter(function(obj) {
  return array2.some(function(obj2) {
    return obj.name== obj2.name;
});
}); 
console.log(Result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destructuring, the `map()` and `.includes()` methods as shown below:

```js
const array1 = [{ name: "sample1" }, { name: "sample2" }, { name: "sample3" }];
const array2 = [{ name: "sample1" }, { name: "sample2" }];

const filtered = array1.filter(
    ({name}) => array2.map(o => o.name).includes(name)
);

console.log( filtered );
```