# Javascript - Check if arrays within an array are the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, comparison, equality

Whats the best way to check if the arrays within an array are the same in my case?

```
var arrSession = [
  {
    type: '1',
    usecase: [ '1' ]
  },
  {
    type: '1',
    usecase: [ '1' ]
  }
];

var checkUsecase = arrSession.every(isSame);

function isSame(obj, index, arr) {
    if (index === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return (
            (obj.type === arr[index - 1].type) &&
            (obj.usecase === arr[index - 1].usecase)
        );
    }
}

console.log('checkUsecase:');
console.log(checkUsecase);
```

The 'usecase' object within the array use to be a string '' and the isSame function used to work. But now they are arrays too. How to change the isSame function?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3j0odpec/

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript) is worth a read. Comparing arrays in Javascript is unfortunately not the easiest thing to do.

Comment: What is the datatype that is used for the `usecase` array elements? Always string? Or maybe more objects, arrays, sets, maps, dates,... etc?

Comment: @PeterSeliger No, this is more than perfect! :-) ... both answers are great, hard to decide which to accept. Thanks a lot for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer too chooses the already proposed [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) based comparison approach ...

```
const isFullItemEquality = arrSession
  .every((item, idx, arr) =>
    idx === 0 || isDeepDataStructureEquality(item, arr[idx - 1])
  );
```

... only that it does not utilize `JSON.stringify`.

For ***sameness / equality comparison of JSON conform data structures*** where performance is important as well, one might consider going with the following recursive implementation of [`isDeepDataStructureEquality`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71016510/2627243) ...

```html
<script>
  // implemented by Peter Seliger
  function isDeepDataStructureEquality(a, b) {
    let isEqual = Object.is(a, b);

    if (!isEqual) {
      if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b)) {

        isEqual = (a.length === b.length) && a.every(
          (item, idx) => isDeepDataStructureEquality(item, b[idx])
        );
      } else if (
        a && b
        && (typeof a === 'object')
        && (typeof b === 'object')
      ) {
        const aKeys = Object.keys(a);
        const bKeys = Object.keys(b);

        isEqual = (aKeys.length === bKeys.length) && aKeys.every(
          (key, idx) => isDeepDataStructureEquality(a[key], b[key])
        );
      }
    }
    return isEqual;
  }
</script>
<script>
  // implemented by Alexander Nenashev
  function isSame(a, b) {

    const iterator = Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b) ? a.keys() : 
    (typeof a === 'object') && (typeof b === 'object') ? Object.keys(a) : null;

    if (iterator) {
        for (const i of iterator) {
            if (!isSame(a[i], b[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    return a === b;

  }
</script>
<script benchmark data-count="10">

  const arrSession = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array
    .from({ length: 300000 })
    .reduce(arr => arr.push(...[{
      type: '1',
      usecase: ['1'],
      child: {
        type: '1',
        usecase: ['1'],
        child: {
          type: '1',
          usecase: ['1'],
          child: {
            type: '1',
            usecase: ['1'],
          },
        },
      },
      child: {
        type: '1',
        usecase: ['1'],
      }
    }]) && arr, [])));

    // countercheck implementations with an unequal data structure.
    // arrSession.at(-1).child.usecase[0] = 0;

    // @benchmark JSON.stringify
    arrSession.every((item, idx, arr) =>
      idx === 0 || JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(arr[idx - 1])
    );
    // @benchmark recursive isSame
    arrSession.every((item, idx, arr) =>
      idx === 0 || isSame(item, arr[idx - 1])
    );
    // @benchmark recursive isDeepDataStructureEquality
    arrSession.every((item, idx, arr) =>
      idx === 0 || isDeepDataStructureEquality(item, arr[idx - 1])
    );
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use of `__proto__` is [discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) -- see the multiple notices on the MDN page.

Comment: @PeterSeliger my bad was to hurry. i definitely saw that using `reduce()` wasn't optimal to handle just 2 values a & b. changed it with the same logic as before just avoiding `reduce()`. so now my function is more comparable to yours in speed terms. i guess you're not against to fix my code in your answer. that's a some drawback of stackoverflow that if you aren't fast enough you get no points even your answer is the best...

Comment: @PeterSeliger comparing array and object key length was a smart move. i did the same in my code before but forgot to add this check today

Answer (score 4):

First we make some recursive compare function to walk nested arrays/objects. Then we run it over the array comparing that the current item is equal to the previous one.

And it's definitely faster than comparing JSON.stringified array items of the OP's data:

```
` Chrome/121
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                       n=2      |      n=20       |     n=200      |    n=2000    
recursive isSame   1.00x x1m 173 | 1.00x x100k 326 | 1.00x x10k 344 | 1.00x x1k 368
JSON.stringify     1.65x x1m 285 | 1.62x x100k 527 | 1.64x x10k 565 | 1.56x x1k 574
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const arrSession = [
    {
        type: '1',
        usecase: ['1']
    },
    {
        type: '1',
        usecase: ['1']
    }
];

const isSameItems = arrSession.every((item, idx, arr) => idx === 0 || isSame(item, arr[idx - 1]));

console.log('the array has all items the same: ', isSameItems);

function isSame(a, b) {

    const iterator = Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b) ? a.keys() : 
    (typeof a === 'object') && (typeof b === 'object') ? Object.keys(a) : null;

    if (iterator) {
        for (const i of iterator) {
            if (!isSame(a[i], b[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    return a === b;

}
```

```js
const $chunk = Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => (
    {
        type: '1',
        usecase: ['1'],
        child: {
            type: '1',
            usecase: ['1'],
            child: {
                type: '1',
                usecase: ['1'],
                child: {
                    type: '1',
                    usecase: ['1'],
                }
            }
        },
        child: {
            type: '1',
            usecase: ['1'],
        }
    }
));

const $input = [];

// @benchmark JSON.stringify

$input.every((item, idx, arr) => idx === 0 || JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(arr[idx - 1]));

// @benchmark recursive isSame

function isSame(a, b) {

    const iterator = Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b) ? a.keys() : 
    (typeof a === 'object') && (typeof b === 'object') ? Object.keys(a) : null;

    if (iterator) {
        for (const i of iterator) {
            if (!isSame(a[i], b[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    return a === b;

}

// @run 

$input.every((item, idx, arr) => idx === 0 || isSame(item, arr[idx - 1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use of `__proto__` is [discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) -- see the multiple notices on the MDN page.

Comment: Also a great answer, thanks for the help! Much appreciated! Hard to decide which answer to accept!